# Childhood "Publications" in Resume

Tags: resume

Is it a good idea to put articles that I wrote at 8 years old, in a school newspaper, in my resume?

For some context: I was told by an orientation guy from my university to put theses articles on my résumé, like if they were publications. These articles were about nature, while I am in electrical engineering. I think it's because "I need to show I have good writing skills."

Edit : I know this question is odd. I just asked it so I can tell the orientation guy that his advice isn't the best.

Comment: Is it relevant to your career in any way?  Is it relevant to the position your applying to?  Most likely the answer is **no**.

Comment: It depends on a lot of things: Which field do you apply? What was about the articles? It is relevant for your new position? How many people read your article? What was the feedback you got?

Comment: I would expect this to be an easy "no", so I'm trying to figure out why you wrote this question. Is there something particularly amazing about these articles you wrote at age 8 that makes you think your potential boss would care about them 10+ years later?

Comment: You will have to provide some more context. In particular, why do you think this might be good idea? If you are applying to be the editor of a children's magazine, then I can see why some employers might find this relevant (and even then, it is a bit of a stretch). For positions in other industries, might not be such a good idea.

Comment: @D.LaRocque How old are you now? Are you particularly proud of these articles for any reason? Did they lead to any awards or scholarships later in life? This seems like a really odd question.

Comment: @theonlydanever I know it's odd, I just asked the question so I can tell the orientation guy that his advice isn't the best.

Comment: @D.LaRocque Welcome to The workplace, by the way.  In the future, it's okay to let your question sit for a few days (or longer) before selecting the best answer.  Once the best answer is selected, people tend to stop providing additional answers.  This may mean that an even better answer ends up not being posted.  Take your time, there is no pressure to answer quickly.

Comment: How did an article you wrote at age 8 even came up in the conversation? Just overall a very odd thing unless this article was amazing and the orientation guy recognized you right away like, "Hey you wrote that article on X at age 8! Man that's amazing I'm glad to meet you."

Comment: @Dan His kids were in the same class as me. Since it was a small school, everything that is done in school committees is known by everyone.

Comment: @D.LaRocque I would tend to think that a well-written cover letter written at age 20-something or a good grade in a high school or college writing/language class would be a better indicator of your "good writing skills" than something you wrote as a child. :)

Comment: Who is the resume supposed to be submitted to? Perhaps he has a point if it will be seen by the same individuals in this committee? I have been in private school and the same teachers since grade 1 teach the same student in grade 12 and remembers various performances and presentations throughout. If that is such a case, including the article may be important but only to this committee.

Comment: Hopefully your writing skills have improved since you were 8. If not, that's one thing worth investing some training in.

Comment: Are you the same guy who was [wondering whether he needs to report his cheating on an exam when he was 8 years old to graduate admissions](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/102175/1201)?

Comment: To be fair, electricity is a naturally occurring phenonmenon.

Comment: Unless you are [Emily Rosa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emily_Rosa), the answer is no.

Comment: My school advised us to do something similar; in one interview, I was openly mocked for it.  Obviously that was unprofessional and I immediately lost all interest in working there, but ultimately they were correct in that it definitely shouldn't have been on my resume.  Always tailor your resume to what the specific employer cares about.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I remember similar stuff when I was studying engineering and went to my university's Career Center for advice and they wanted me to put some irrelevant (to engineering) fluff on my resume. As an engineer, your resume will be a little different from the resumes by kids in other majors.

If you look around, you will probably find that your engineering department can provide better resources for resume advice for you. The best resume advice I got was from a resume workshop hosted by one of the engineering organizations (in my case it was SWE, but look for anything hosted by IEEE (and join your student chapter if you haven't already!), CSCE (ASCE for any Americans reading this), ASME or maybe ACM). It was open to all engineering students at the school and a couple engineers from a local company came and talked about what *they* liked to see on resumes. It was also a good networking opportunity, before I even really realized what networking was, that led pretty directly to getting my first interview.

Oh, and the best career advice I've ever gotten is: don't burn any bridges. No matter what advice you get on your resume, from here or anywhere else, don't go tell the orientation guy he's full of it. It's entirely likely you'll be working with this guy, or someone who knows him, before long. If you see him again there's no need to tell him he was wrong about anything. You should thank him for his time and, if he presses you on how your resume turned out, just say that you got some tailored advice from an engineering-focused organization.

Comment: That last paragraph is spectacularly accurate. The world is downright * **TINY** * When you get right down to it. You'd be surprised who you end up working with/for. +1

Comment: Your answer gives me good solutions for improving my resume. I will therefore say that it solves my question.

Answer (score 52):

Unless the article is highly articulate and amazing for a 8 years old child prodigy, I wouldn't include it. Also what was it published in? Unless it's a national scientific journal or something recognized by researchers, I wouldn't include it.

Matter of fact, I'm not sure what sort of advice you gotten from your university but this doesn't sound like you're getting advised correctly. I would seek other opinions before using this individual again.

Comment: That's why I'm asking here.

Comment: The only other way I can imagine it being deemed useful is to show OPs early inclination and eagerness to write. Since he is an engineer, this might not be enough to warrant an inclusion.

Comment: yea, if this is for his first job it also might be a good conversation starter, and help fill out his ONE PAGE resume.

Comment: Don't include these articles in your resumé, of course, but why not mentioning them during an interview (as an anecdote, with a smile), if the discussion comes to the writing part of your skills?

Answer (score 25):

That would get your resume noticed all right but not in a good way. Hiring officials have no interest at all concerning your childhood. They would think you were odd or strange for including this information and odd is not what most employers are looking for.

Comment: In that movie Big with Tom Hanks I wonder if when he grows up he could use the toy company as a resume point? At age 10 I helped a fortune 500 company increase profit by 800% utilizing new computerized story telling software.

Comment: @Dan, that is fiction. And frankly if you won the Nobel prize at ten or 8 or something of that magnitude, you wouldn't need to ask the question of whether to include it. But for 99.999999 % of all things that you could have done at 8, no it is just going to make people laugh at you.

Comment: Yes, yes, just kidding but yes it does seem odd to include such a thing. Equivalent to submitting macaroni pictures you made unless it is particularly outstanding and recognized by some authority.

Comment: Indeed!  For a bit of anecdotal evidence, I recently had a resume come across my desk for an engineering position that had the candidates picture up top and started with "Life experience" (kids, pets, hobbies).  I looked at the resume quizzically for a minute and then just ignored that part of the resume.  It didn't stop me from considering them as a candidate, but it did make me pause and not in a good way.  I care about your job qualifications.  Some of that stuff matters when we get to the "team fit" portion, but that's not what I care about in a resume.

Comment: 10-year-old Nobel prize winners are hardly going to be sending out resumes like us mere mortals.

Comment: A friend was asked to review a job candidate at her university. Her review: "He has a Nobel Prize. I am a very junior assistant professor. I think he's qualified."

Comment: "I'm not crazy. My mother had me tested."

Answer (score 6):

Whenever you wonder if you should or should not put something in your resume, ask yourself this:

**What does this accomplishment say about my current qualifications for this job?**

When you are an adult and mention something you wrote while you were 8, it doesn't say anything about you at all.

- Your interests will have changed
- Your writing skills will have drastically improved (I hope...)
- The quality threshold of a school newspaper written by 8 year olds will be ridiculously low compared to any quality standards you will be measured by as an adult.

Also, do you seriously want someone to dig out those articles you wrote back then and use them to judge your current writing skills? Assuming someone would actually do this (very, **very** unlikely), do you think that it would be an accurate representation of your writing skills today? I doubt it.

So I would consider it irrelevant information and leave it out.

By the way, if you want to demonstrate your writing skills, then the cover letter of your applicaton should already be a good demonstration.

Comment: Also starting a blog might help. You can put on your resume that you maintain a blog in your field and put a link on it, preferably a personal website and/or professional setup. That would accomplish showing off without any relevant professional skillset.

Answer (score 0):

The Resume / CV's purpose is to get you into the interview group, no more and no less.

To do that your resume has to have "hooks" in it that catch the reader's attention and put your info in the "interview pile" instead of the reject pile.

Those hooks need to be tailored for each application based on the advert and whatever else you can find out about the employer.

> If the specific job involves "working on the company newsletter" then showing some pre-exposure would be of benefit.  Similar tasks might be "assisting salespeople in technical aspects of their proposals" or documentation.

The CV is a means to an end.  Once you get an interview then your performance at that interview is what gets you a job offer.  The CV is nothing more than notes and you have to show you've got the skills and that you would be a good fit for the organisation.